# Divide identical items of different colors between multiple people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have 5 red balls and 8 green balls, and then split them between persons A, B, and C. How many ways are there to split them?

If we were to arrange the balls we could use the multinomial function, but I don't know what to do when we want to group them as well.

Comment: Hint: The ways you split the 5 red balls between A, B, and C is completely independent of the ways you split the 8 green balls. So you can multiply the number ways to split the red balls by the number of ways to split the green balls.

Comment: Thanks! That is actually kind of intuitive now that I think about it

Answer (score 0):

Try using a method like ["sticks and stones"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) (a.k.a. "stars and bars") and separate the problem into 2 parts like 2012ssohn said. For 3 people you should verify that you need 2 "sticks".